# __bridge causes EXEC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, exc-bad-access

During ARC Conversion, Xcode suggested changing

```
NSMutableData *b = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:[value getMutableData] 
                                         length:[value length]];
```

to

```
NSMutableData *b = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:
                       (__bridge const void *)([value getMutableData]) 
                                         length:[value length]];
```

The non-ARC version runs fine but the ARC version throws `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1)`.

Value is custom object that has a NSMutableData attribute named valueObject.  GetMutableData is an accessor to return the valueObject.

This is a flattening operation and is adding `b` to a stream.

Is there a release or free that I need to call?

Comment: What kind of object is `value`? What does `[value getMutableData]` return?

Comment: NSMutableData does not define a getMutableData method. Did you add a category, or where you trying to use the mutableBytes method?

Comment: There's no method on `NSData` or `NSMutableData` called `getMutableData`, so how can `value` be `NSMutableData`? And if it is, why are you creating _another_ `NSMutableData` from it? Is this your real code?

Comment: As I was stepping through the debug process, the ARC change was the likely source of the problem, since the code worked pre ARC.  As I mention below the pre-ARC was more forgiving in cloning data in the datawithbytes.  I changed to an explicit clone and the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with this is that you're trying to bridge cast a retainable object pointer type to another retainable object pointer type.

You don't need to be casting your getMutableData to a `void *`. All you need to pass in is a bytes array.

Here's a better explanation:
http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#arc-objects-restrictions-conversion

This clearly specifies the following:

> For example, an Objective-C object pointer shall not be converted to
>   void*.

Here's a better explanation of how to use bridged casts:
http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#bridged-casts

Some solution to your problem, if I understand correctly, would be that `value` has a method that returns an `NSMutableData` object.

```
NSMutableData *b = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:[[value getMutableData] bytes] 
                                         length:[value length]];
```

Comment: Simon -Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. It seems that the non-Arc was much kinder when it came to cloning data.  I added a clone accessor to my object and that did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

> Value is custom object that has a NSMutableData attribute named valueObject. GetMutableData is an accessor to return the valueObject.

Considering the above statement, why don't you just create a variable storing the return value of the accessor?

```
NSMutableData *someData = [value getMutableData];
```